# Cant change title for tooltip in select2 selected options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2-4

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.reminder-numbers-select').select2({
    tags: true,
    dir: "rtl",
    dropdownAutoWidth: true,
    width: '100%',
  })
});
```

```css
#rem-no {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-aOG0c6nPNzGk+5zjwyJaoRUgCdOrfSDhmMID2u4+OIslr0GjpLKo7Xm0Ao3xmpM4T8AmIouRkqwj1nrdVsLKEQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" integrity="sha512-oM24YOsgj1yCDHwW895ZtK7zoDQgscnwkCLXcPUNsTRwoW1T1nDIuwkZq/O6oLYjpuz4DfEDr02Pguu68r4/3w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" integrity="sha512-9h7XRlUeUwcHUf9bNiWSTO9ovOWFELxTlViP801e5BbwNJ5ir9ua6L20tEroWZdm+HFBAWBLx2qH4l4QHHlRyg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-uto9mlQzrs59VwILcLiRYeLKPPbS/bT71da/OEBYEwcdNUk8jYIy+D176RYoop1Da+f9mvkYrmj5MCLZWEtQuA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <select class="reminder-numbers-select js-example-basic-multiple" id="rem-no" name="numbers[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="xyz" selected>Javascript</option>
        <option value="efg" selected>CSS</option>
        <option value="abc" selected>HTML</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is that when hovering over the selected option, the tooltip is shown and it is the text written inside the option element, but I want that tooltip to show the value `xyz` or `abc`.

I tried to loop through the element containing the information related to this

```
$($('span.select2.select2-container').find('.select2-selection__rendered')).children().map(function () {
        
})
```

but this doesnt work. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `title` attribute to the options with the desired tooltip.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.reminder-numbers-select').select2({
    tags: true,
    dir: "rtl",
    dropdownAutoWidth: true,
    width: '100%',
  })
});
```

```css
#rem-no {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-aOG0c6nPNzGk+5zjwyJaoRUgCdOrfSDhmMID2u4+OIslr0GjpLKo7Xm0Ao3xmpM4T8AmIouRkqwj1nrdVsLKEQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" integrity="sha512-oM24YOsgj1yCDHwW895ZtK7zoDQgscnwkCLXcPUNsTRwoW1T1nDIuwkZq/O6oLYjpuz4DfEDr02Pguu68r4/3w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" integrity="sha512-9h7XRlUeUwcHUf9bNiWSTO9ovOWFELxTlViP801e5BbwNJ5ir9ua6L20tEroWZdm+HFBAWBLx2qH4l4QHHlRyg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-uto9mlQzrs59VwILcLiRYeLKPPbS/bT71da/OEBYEwcdNUk8jYIy+D176RYoop1Da+f9mvkYrmj5MCLZWEtQuA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <select class="reminder-numbers-select js-example-basic-multiple" id="rem-no" name="numbers[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="xyz" title="xyz" selected>Javascript</option>
        <option value="efg" title="efg" selected>CSS</option>
        <option value="abc" title="abc" selected>HTML</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```